# How to get dynamically created checkbox list selected values in Angular?

Tags: jquery, css, angular, mean-stack

Here is my dynamically created checkboxes list

```
<span *ngFor="let name of _category">
<span class="TextMaroonBold"> {{name.AliasName}}</span>
<div class="ex1">
<span *ngFor="let option of name.arrOptions" class="checkbox">

        <div class="form-check" style="padding-left: 35px;">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" (change)="changed(evt)" name="exampleRadios" id={{name.DisplayOrder}} value="{{option.options}}">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                {{option.options}}
            </label>
        </div>

</span>
```

This is how my checkbox list looks :-

[image]

Now what i want is to get the checkboxlist name/ID and its selected values. E.g. If I have selected some values in "certification" check box I should get the name of the checkboxlist i.e. Certification and its selected values.

Comment: `(change)="changed(evt)"` what does this do?

Comment: I'm asking this because you are using angular, which means that you are constructing your view from a data model.  If you check an option on the page, that selection should be reflected some how in your data model.  You should not have to look at the view to figure out which options are selected or get their names.  All that information should be available in your data model

Comment: nothing really .. was trying something

Comment: Which, related to my second comment, it doesn't make sense that you also tagged this question with `jquery`.  This is entirely possible using angular and not bringing in a third party library.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you. I am not sure if I am having the selection information in my data model. Could you please help me to identify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rohit, the question is "what about your data?". It's looks like you has some like

```
_category=[
   {
     name:"Certification"
     arrOptions:[{options:"Current"},{options:"Process"}..]
   }, 
   {
     name:"Heigth"
     arrOptions:[{options:"50-80 cm"},{options:"81-120 cm"}..]
   },
   ... 
]
```

You can simply use in our inputs [(ngModel)]

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="option.checked"
 name="exampleRadios" id={{name.DisplayOrder}} >
```

This add a new property to your elements options called checked that make it true/false, just add in your .html to see it

```
<pre>
{{_category|json}}
</pre>
```

Well, you can get an array of Certification, Heigth and Width selected, so you can do

```
const certifications=_category[0].arrOptions.filter(o=>o.checked).map(o=>o.options)
const heigths=_category[1].arrOptions.filter(o=>o.checked).map(o=>o.options)
const widths=_category[2].arrOptions.filter(o=>o.checked).map(o=>o.options)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have simulated the scenario on this stackblitz playground - [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamically-created-checkbox-selectedvalue)

It will dynamically show you the changes you make on checkbox in pre tag at the bottom.
Hope it helps. 
--Thanks